# Load aspx page in a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Am using the below code to load aspx page in a div tag. But its not working.Please help me to fix this issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div_more_pack').load('dss_more_pack.aspx');
    });  
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
  </title>
    <link href="CSS/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/WebResource.axd?d=jXYvAvdTPQseQ0chjS0NJiUVoAt1FHDKI8RqT3Bub606dQEw4MJ7tgPzZQtv2Vbv0&amp;t=634959154400107513" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
.uc_more_pack_Cust_tab_tab_service_tree_package_0 { color:Black;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none; }

   </style>
 </head>

 <body>
<form method="post" action="dss_more_pack.aspx" id="form1">
    <div class="aspNetHidden">
     <input type="hidden" name="uc_more_pack_Cust_tab_ClientState" id="uc_more_pack_Cust_tab_ClientState" value="{&quot;ActiveTabIndex&quot;:0,&quot;TabState&quot;:[true,true,true,true,true,true,true]}" />

     <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />

     <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />

     <input type="hidden" name="uc_more_pack_Cust_tab_tab_service_tree_package_ExpandState" id="uc_more_pack_Cust_tab_tab_service_tree_package_ExpandState" value="cccnccncccnnnccncncccn" />

      <input type="hidden" name="uc_more_pack_Cust_tab_tab_service_tree_package_SelectedNode" id="uc_more_pack_Cust_tab_tab_service_tree_package_SelectedNode" value="" />

      <input type="hidden" name="uc_more_pack_Cust_tab_tab_service_tree_package_PopulateLog" id="uc_more_pack_Cust_tab_tab_service_tree_package_PopulateLog" value="" />

      <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

 var theForm = document.forms['form1'];

 if (!theForm) {

    theForm = document.form1;

 }
```

function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {

```
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {

    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;

    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;

    theForm.submit();

    }

 }

 //]]>

 </script>





 <script src="/WebResource.axd?d=NGWHhrhQxVdi6Y5BQUr6nQ2&amp;t=634929307791941336" type="text/javascript"></script>





<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=s72EBzlqyW6dq8nmj_nsuG0cSaf4Z0nmMamkiAEH_xLorZXIBJ71Hr3YwVOJXj15DhZSDRzQxMITNszVnYKjJQ2&amp;t=1e961a8d" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[



    function TreeView_PopulateNodeDoCallBack(context,param) {

    WebForm_DoCallback(context.data.treeViewID,param,TreeView_ProcessNodeData,context,TreeView_ProcessNodeData,false);

   }

 var uc_more_pack_Cust_tab_tab_service_tree_package_Data = null;//]]>

 </script>



 <script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=3qhHLSWv5cU_c2_8JyEg-cfozgETQm0npL12m8PkbOAhQRNtVs8YWfe_0n0f7Vjn0&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript">          </script>
```

//

```
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');

//]]>
```

Comment: There could be endless possibilities to what this could be. Provide more information. Post your HTML code, and detail more what you mean by "its not working". Is it running the script? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Did you use the browser's Developer Tools (F12 in Chrome and IE) to look at the Console for any errors? Can you browse to dss_more_pack.aspx in the browser and does that work?

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be the path of the `page`.

It should be at the same level.

If they are not at the same level then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#div_more_pack').load('dss_more_pack.aspx');
    });  
</script>
```

change to

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div_more_pack').load('../dss_more_pack.aspx');//exact path
    });  
 </script>
```

### Edit 1

You can edit you approach and see what is the `error`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div_more_pack').load('dss_more_pack.aspx', function(response, status, xhr)
    {
       if (status == "error") {
          var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
         alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
     }
  );
});
```

### Edit 2:-

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div_more_pack').load('dss_more_pack.aspx', function(response, status, xhr)
    {
       alert(response);
     }
  );
});
```

Comment: am using the above method but it not showing any error.

Comment: I also assign the text for that div. Its displayed and disappear suddenly.

Comment: can you alert `"response"` and see what is coming?

Comment: @user1951007 what is there on page `dss_more_pack.aspx`?

Comment: its coming. I checked that.

Comment: its having some aspx page design and code.

Comment: @user1951007 what is there in alert(response);? I have suggested in my code

Comment: Thanks for your reply it returns the following code.

Comment: @user1951007 I see thee text in your question but there is nothing which will displayed in the <div> since all are html tags.

Comment: @user1951007 you can try loading a simple page with some static content.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AJAX

```
$.get('dss_more_pack.aspx', {}, function(data) {
   $('#div_more_pack').html(data);
});
```

You can also use

```
$.post('url', parameters, callback)
```

Refer [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/)

Comment: This shouldn't be required.