# Jquery load aspx into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

My earlier post [Load aspx page in a div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850246/load-aspx-page-in-a-div-tag). Am using the below code to load aspx page in a div. But i can't load the aspx page into div.Please any one help me to do this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Plan_search/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Plan_search/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            $("#package").load("dss_more_pack.aspx", {}, function (data) {
                alert("loading complete");
            });
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert("Error Status : " + ex);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: May be this is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467488/how-to-dynamically-load-the-aspx-page-in-div-tag ?

Comment: Just wondering, is there a reason you're using `try/catch` for that block of code? If you want to catch an error with `.load`, you wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: I put that try catch for reading error if any?

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is that you can use IFrames as shown below:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youraspxpage.aspx" height="100%">
            Alternative text for browsers that do not understand IFrames.
</iframe>
```

Or as in the comments above you can try this

[how to dynamically load the aspx page in div tag ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467488/how-to-dynamically-load-the-aspx-page-in-div-tag)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should load a webpage(aspx page) in a iframe not in a div. Iframe can be under
div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#package").load("dss_more_pack.aspx", function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "Error Status : ";
                console.log(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
            alert("loading complete");
        });
});
```